# Pytest - How to pass function argument from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, pytest, fixtures

I have some test cases that I run using different pytest markers. I had a single configuration file from which I got the values for variables I used in these test cases. Now the configuration files have increased and it will keep on increasing.

Initially I thought I'll use `pytest_generate_tests` from here https://docs.pytest.org/en/doc-warnings/parametrize.html

```
# content of main.py file

import json
import pytest
import other_py_files

...
...
...
...

def configfile(conf):
    config = open(str(conf) + ".json", 'r')
    jsonData = config.read()
    obj = json.loads(jsonData)
    globals()['Name'] = obj['Name']
    globals()['Age'] = obj['Age']
    globals()['Dob'] = obj['Dob']
    globals()['Reg_No'] = obj['Reg_No']

@pytest.mark.testA
def testA(Name, Age, Dob, Reg_No, ...., some parameters):
    ...........
    ...........

@pytest.mark.testB
def testB(Name, Age, ...., other parameters):
    ..........
    ..........
```

This is the content of conftest.py. There are some other python files as well which I import into the main.py file.

```
# content of conftest.py

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--conf", action="append", default=[],
        help="Name of the conf file to pass to test functions")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'conf' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("conf", metafunc.config.option.conf)
```

Now I run `pytest -q --conf="Config_XYZ" -m "testA"` but nothing happens. Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Edit 1:

Json contents look like this. I'm trying to take the json contents from this and pass it on to the tests by calling their markers. The json file to open and the test to be run has to be given through the commandline.

```
{
  "Name": "abc",
  "Age": "123",
  "Dob": "00-00-0000",
  "Reg_No": "12345678"
}
```

Comment: Where does `configfile` get called? Also, your code seems to imply that `conf` is  a fixture, but you don't use it in the tests. Note that you cannot use a fixture as a parameter in a non-test function (if this is waht you do). Can you show what `conf` actuall is?

Comment: You are not using the config file anywhere. Are you trying to apply config to different markers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run pytest markers based on command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693338/run-pytest-markers-based-on-command-line-argument)